# Response from webservice : method not allowed

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, post

I have a .net web service with the following OperationContract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "testing2?coName={coName}&password={password}")] 
    string testing2(string coName, string password);
```

when trying to access it from my local host:

```
http://.../service1.svc/testing2?coName=abcd&password=1234qw
```

(... is my local host)

I get the following response in my browser:

Service

Method not allowed.

Comment: "Method not allowed" usually indicates there's something wrong on the server-side. Have you tried to debug the service?

Comment: When my OperationContract was using a GET method and passing a single parameter it was working fine. Now I need to use a POST method and pass 2 parameters. All my other OperationalContract works when it being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke a method that expects type POST, you should POST it, or else it won't register correctly. If you're invoking such method by visiting its URL, it will deny the access (that's GET method, that's why it worked previously). If you're not actually posting some data in the body, switch back to GET if you want to invoke it by using an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try enable anonymous access on this webservice

```
<security>
 <authentication>
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
 </authentication>
</security>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how I can do it?

Comment: If that is WCF somewhere in Web.Config. You probably have forms authentication defined in config but not anonymous
Check update in anwser.

Comment: There's a basic hint - if the "answer" is only a single question, it's no longer an answer, but rather a comment. This is not a forum where you discuss stuff. If you have some questions to make the OP's question more clear - post it as a comment.

Comment: @walther Because of people like you where any answer and question is evaluated 100 times this forum is no longer usable to anyone and quality is dropped significantly.

Comment: Once again, this is NOT a forum. This is a Q&A site - someone asks a question, a programmer answers it. BUT, not with an another question. The answer has to provide a solution. Please, if you want to keep arguing, read the basic rules of StackExchange sites first.

Answer (score 0):

Method not allowed has error code HTTP error code 405. The Possible reason you are getting is because of missing Request property Accept.
I really don't want to give you an incorrect code, because I don't know wcf, but this is what you can do once you set a connection,

`connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");`

You need to find similar method that can achieve this task in wcf.

Read [this page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more information.

The other reason is if that particular method POST is not allowed on the webservice end, that's when you will get method not allowed.